# PDFBox generate so blacked line when I zoom out

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, dotted-line

When I try to print lines using PDFBox, it creates line so blacked when I zoom out generated pdf file.

I'm creating a dashed pattern using content stream with line methods (moveTo, lineTo). For dash pattern and setting specific size I use methods (lineWidth, setLineDashPattern).

You can see code on my github repo (https://github.com/dmmax/pdfbox-dotted-pattern/blob/master/src/main/java/me/dmmax/pdfbox/dottedpattern/Main.java)

Below picture with opened two files: my result (left side) and example how it should look like (right side). Zoom of both files is 50%.

[image: Compare my result with example]
Or you can check on your computer, just download two files:
1) My result: https://github.com/dmmax/pdfbox-dotted-pattern/blob/master/print.pdf
2) Example: https://github.com/dmmax/pdfbox-dotted-pattern/blob/master/informationyoushouldknow.pdf

Does anyone know how to fix blacked lines when I zoom out result pdf?

Comment: To create a pattern, use a pattern "color" and not a bunch of dashed lines. See the CreatePatternsPDF.java example in the source code download. Modify that one to your needs.

Comment: Btw, such "chess patterns" are terrible when printed and scanned, these increase the file size.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm trying it right now. I can print line and it remains to solve the problem with the phase of next line. When I printed lines (using moveTo, lineTo). Hope that this option will work without so blacked lines when zoom out

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I implemented this approach but not fully understand how to control it. For example: I want to start first line with space 1.2 pixels and second line start without space. I create next pattern: "0.3 w 0 0.3 m 0.3 0.3 l s  0.3 w 1.2 1.5 m 1.5 1.5 l s" but sometimes it start from second line sometimes from first. How is control that?

Comment: I can't tell because I can't visualize this in my mind. But you have to understand that these patterns are tiles. The end of one is the start of the next one. So you have to take care that what happens on the right visually matches with what happens at the left, or it will look weird. Same for top / bottom. I wrote that example 2 years ago and it took me several attempts to get it right. And change XStep YStep and BBox if needed.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr do you know another approach? Because pattern "color" so blacked too...

Comment: No everything else is second best. Your sample PDF file uses an image.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I also tried to add image but size of file more than 2Mb (in this file I use about 100 dotted and dashed patterns) but size of example file is about 150-200Kb (and count of patterns about 100). I don't understand how to reduce size of file. Do you have any variants? I use next approach: 1) from pdf file get image of pattern with count of lines (9, 17, 26 etc); 2) Created PDImageXObject using next class: LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, image); 3) In final put xobject in pdf contentStream.drawImage(xobject, x, y, width, height);

Comment: You can reuse the pdimagexobject object in the pdf, even on different pages of the same pdf.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes, I did it and after that reduce size of file from 2.5Mb to 1.7Mb :) I hope that I can compress more size. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that, but still kindof big, IMHO. You could try to reduce the color depth of your source images before using them (e.g. with IrfanView). And if you have lots of time (and want to train your skills), then try working with patterns again. Because now that you have a working solution, there's nothing to lose.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I checked my solution with printing dot-pattern using image and have some problem with it. Could you check please pdf file https://github.com/dmmax/pdfbox-dotted-pattern/blob/master/print.pdf ? First dot-pattern generated by lines (moveTo, lineTo methods) but second dot-pattern use same mechanism and convert this pattern to pdf and after that pdf convert to BufferedImage (BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300, ImageType.BINARY)). And I have so strange result, some of lines shifted and sometimes printed two dots near each other

Comment: That is a flaw in java when scaling images.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr do you have ideas what should I do with it?

Comment: No… you could try different images with different point sizes and see which one renders best at 300dpi. Oh, I see you are rendering to BINARY. Certain optimizations are off by default because people asked for this. Then the solution would be to render to gray, or to set the rendering hints in PDFRenderer.

Comment: See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4530

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I resolved problem with shifted dots. I increased size of each dot from 0.3 pixels to 0.3 * 3.34 = 1.002 (need more than 1). And after that I generate dot-pattern that increases 3.34 times. I get an image and draw it normal size. But now I have problem with size of file... it's so big. I see that drawImage save each image in resources. Could you suggest how to optimize it? Maybe reuse this object?

Comment: Yes I wrote that in an earlier comment.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Do you mean "reduce the color depth of your source images"? Or about reuse pdfimagexobject? If about reuse. Could you suggest how to do it? I analyzed before how to work drawImage method but this method use resources of page. In this method use next lines: writeOperand(resources.add(image)); writeOperator("Do"); and this methods are private. Guide me to the path of truth.

Comment: Reduce color depth - you already did, your image is b/w. Reuse your objects means you should reuse the PDImageXObject object.

Comment: If you don't understand, please create a new question, with your code, the pdfbox version and the result PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr ok, thank you, again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank a lot to @TilmanHausherr with his big help in this question. 
If you have so blacked line(-s) in zoom out of pdf then this happens because pdf render a lot of small objects but in zoom out size have the same (or close to it) size.

For me resolve this problem is generate dot/dash pattern (with needed count of lines) in another pdf and after that I convert pdf to XObject and print on my current pdf.

Yes it takes up more space, but there are no blackouts